# Best Way To Store Multiple Arrays Associated Together - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Throughout my iOS program. I create multiple arrays that all work together to make the program work. Now I need a method to store the arrays even when the iPhone is turned off. So I need these arrays to be stored like files that only I can touch.

I really would like to use User Defaults, but I just don't know if that is what I need. I have questions like:

1. How long will my data last in User Defaults?
2. When could you possibly lose the data?

If I was able to store arrays in User Defaults, how might I go about **storing arrays in NSDictionaries**? That way I could keep of my associated arrays together and give each array a specific key.

Comment: why don't you used SQLite because if you have Model classes it will not gone save in NSUserDefault, try other option save data in NSDocumentDictionary as plist format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

store array as NSData as in NSDefaults

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:urArray1] forKey:@"Array1"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:urArray2] forKey:@"Array2"];
```

and read it as

```
 NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Array1"];
 if (dataRepresentingSavedArray != nil)
      NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is to store the arrays on the disk and then (when you actually need them) get them back. You can start by seeing if the objects inside your `NSMutableArrays` conform with the `NSCoding` protocol. You can then simply write them to disk and load them when you need. For that you can use `NSKeyedArchiver` class.

---

As @The Saad pointed, and well, you can store the arrays using that piece of code. Although I wouldn't recommend it. You can check @roronoa zorro answer, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well NSuSerDefaults is a way of storing persistent data in iPhone and you don't have to worry about losing of data or about it's persisitency as long as the application remains on the iPhone.
    Yes, you can store the NSDictionary object in NSUserDefaults but it is advisable to use it for small Data.For bigger data you can use sqlite or any other DB.

Here's the [Tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/) For NSUserDefault

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults` basically just a wrapper around property list serialization.

> NSUserDefaults provides a programmatic interface to Mac OS X's
>   preferences system. preferences are actually stored to the disk, they
>   are written to the user's Library/Preferences/ directory with the file
>   name equal to the bundle identifier with a plist extension.

Take a look at MikeBeam's article [here](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2001/08/24/cocoa.html?page=3)